# Confusion about Box-and-pointer diagram using Racket

Tags: racket, diagram

[image]

I am confused about where I got wrong in translating this diagram into Racket code using "list" notation.
For the code, I wrote

```
(list 'greetings
  (list 'howdy 'hi "hello")
  (list "yo" 0.7734
        (list 'hola 'bonjour)))
```

But it turns out that this code is incorrect. I looked up the list notation definition but I couldn't find what's wrong. Could anyone give me a hint about where I got wrong? Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"yo"`, `0.7734`, and `(list 'hola 'bonjour)` belong to the top level list:

```
(define sublist1 (list 'howdy 'hi "hello"))

(define sublist2 (list 'hola 'bonjour))

(list 'greetings sublist1 "yo" 0.7734 sublist2)

(list 'greetings (list 'howdy 'hi "hello") "yo" 0.7734 (list 'hola 'bonjour))
```